# Inheritance Inversion HOC Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following this [Inheritance Inversion Guide](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.3trpb8u58) I keep getting the error:

> cannot call a class as a function.

It works if I change `class extends MyComponent` to `React.Component` but that isn't what I want.

What am I doing wrong?

```
const MyComponent = () => (
    <Child />
);

const wrappedComponent = MyComponent => class extends MyComponent {
  render() {
    //Doesn't get here
  }
};

const WrappedComponent = wrappedComponent(MyComponent);

ReactDOM.render(
<WrappedComponent />,
document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: `class` requires a `new` keyword to be called unlike functions. I've always seen HOCs written with functions and not `class`; Then, returns a `class` inside the HOC

Comment: @AdemolaAdegbuyi I am already returning a class inside the HOC and you don't call new keywords on React functions. This isn't native JS.

Comment: Oh! I see. Why are you extending `MyComponent` instead of `React.Component` cos' that seem to be where the problem is coming from?

Comment: @AdemolaAdegbuyi thats the entire point. Read the link I posted.

Comment: If you want to use a `class` as a component, it is to eventually extend `React.Component`. Therefore `MyComponent` needs to extend `React.Component`.

Comment: @FelixKling I thought so as much before reading the medium post on Inheritance inversion. You only extend `React.Component` when using the `Props Proxy` Method and extend The `ProposedComponent` when using the `Inheritance Inversion` method. It'd be fun to take a peek at the medium post tho because i learnt a lot from it  

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always been used to `Props Proxy` didn't know about this `Inheritance inversion` method but now i know, thanks to you

I found out that II don't work on stateless components, so you'd have to change your functional component to a class based component.

And to make everything work just as fine, don't forget to return `super.render()` in the HOC. I have it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/ooade/qaudnzk6/